# Can an extension associate a filepath to json in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible for a visual studio code extension to make a file-path use a specific language, like `files.associations`.

This is to [associate a json schema](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributesjsonvalidation) with a specific unusual json file, with its [schema](https://github.com/Levertion/minecraft-json-schemas/blob/master/pack.mcmeta.json). The schema association is working fine, but only if I manually set the file grammar to json. Is there any way to do this automatically with the extension (not for example by adding an association in user settings).

Edit: 6th October
Still unresolved, cannot see an official way to do this, however, I have got it working by doing:

```
let config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration()
if (config.get("files.associations")["*.mcmeta"] == undefined && !context.globalState.get("mcmeta- updated")) {
    let object = config.get("files.associations");
    object["*.mcmeta"] = "json";
    config.update("files.associations", object, true);
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage("...");
}
context.globalState.update("mcmeta-updated", true);
```

Which is essentially a massive hack to update the files.association property in the global settings